# R I want to remove those red lines

Tags: r, encoding, rstudio

I want to remove those red lines in r studio.
I upgraded to the latest version, according to someone's suggestion.
But it is not working.

The problem occurs when I write Korean words. 
The default encoding is UTF-8.

[image]

I found a similar problem here, but it didn't work for me.
https://community.rstudio.com/t/why-and-where-is-a-an-unexpected-token-in-r-and-how-should-i-deal-with-it/26496/4

```
df$번호
df$이름
df$성별
```

[image]

Comment: I am not seeing this issue using the latest RStudio 1.2.1335 on Windows 10. What version and OS are you using?

Comment: Need [MCVE]. Use ‘dput’

Comment: @neifws I am using RStudio 1.2.1572 on Windows 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug -- unfortunately, the RStudio diagnostics system does not correctly handle multibyte characters in R Markdown documents on Windows. This will hopefully be fixed in the next release (v1.3).